How to add commas to a text string in Excel?
I have the following number 420001446110 to change to 42,0001,4461,10.
Which function or formula would I use to make this change?

If excel recognizes the number sas a value, not text, you can right-click the cell, cell properties, and change the notation to custom to 0,000.

You can try:
=TEXT(A1,"00\,0000\,0000\,00")

